# How to request more space from superview / superviewcontroller iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, space

i recently started to develop a iOS app with mono touch. My question is about the layout process. Currently all my superviews decide how much space the subviews get.

```
override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    this.subview1.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), new SizeF(10, 10));
    this.subview2.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 15), new SizeF(10, 10));
}
```

But now i am trying to display a `UITableView` which height depends from the content. So what is the correct way to tell the Superview that i need a specific height?

I´ve got the same problem displaying a `UITableView` in a Popover. A UIPopoverController takes another UIViewController and displays it in a Popover. What is the appropriated way of telling the `UIPopoverController` that i need a specific Size?

Comment: You can access the superview of a view by calling [<view> superview]. You can set your sizes based on the size of the superview.

Comment: so i need to subview UITableView and override the layout subviews method and there changed my size according to my superview. Is this the recommended way from apple to request a size? my superview contains a few more subviews so my superview should decide wether the subview should get the size or stay with its actual size. i just want to say to my superview hey if you want to display me with all my content i need a size of...

Comment: Thats not a good approach. Can you not just set the size of the view based on its content and then add it in the superview ?

Comment: the data of the table view is changed dynamically from another module. when the data has changed the source property of the UITableView is set to a new UITableViewSource and the Reload method of the tableview is called. i dont think that it was on mind of the developers that everytime the data changes you have to add a new tableview.

Comment: I dont get it mate. If the data changes, i.e. you will have more cells in the table, then you will simply be scrolling them ? That should not affect the height of the table view ?

Comment: yeah sure, lets just say i got 120x300 points space in my superview reserved for the UITableView and every row in the table view is 100 points high. at first we insert 2 rows so the height of the tableView should be 200 right? than we insert another 2 rows and required size of the UITableView to display it without Scrollbars would be 400 but i only got 300 space so ill say you are 300 high and you have to add scrollbars. i want i dynamically growing UITableView and a dynamically  resized PopoverView i hope this clears things up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all responses although they not completely resolved my issue. but now i think i got a solution to went with.

iOS does natively not support a bottom-up-layout process. so the element at the top of the hierarchy should trigger the layout-process and ask its subview how big it wants to be. so if new data comes from your business models the ViewController first has to handel it and then push it to the tableView that presents the data. after that he triggers the layout process and asks the tableView how big it has to be in order to present all data without scrolling (simply can get the the required size via the `ContentSize` property).

What i also didn´t know is that there is a special property for for the size needed for a view controller to be presented it in a Popover `ContentSizeForViewInPopover`. There is a mechanism integrated in iOS where you can listen to changes made to a Property. The PopoverController listens to the changes made to this property and automatically resizes himself to fit this Size. So all you have to do in the ContentViewController is setting the value of the `ContentSizeForViewInPopover` property and the PopoverController gets resized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too difficult:

- Pass the parent view/popover instance into your `UITableViewSource`, this could be via its constructor, a public property or field, etc.
- When you need to modify the parent control's size form within the table source, you should have access to its `Frame` or `ContentSize` property to do so

Does this resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case of UITableView you should override the GetHeightForRow method of UITableViewSource.
This method runs for every cell prior to it's being rendered and returns its height.

So you can calculate height based on cell underlaying data source or cell view directly (you can refer it from table by NSpath property)